# Trying to put axios data in a variable with a return function, not working (React)

Tags: reactjs, json, ajax, axios

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import axios from "axios";

const BASEURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";


function axiosTest() {
    return axios.get(BASEURL).then(response => response.data)
}


function stepTwo(){
axiosTest()
        .then(data =>{
           
           var namesArray = data;
           //console.log(namesArray);
          return namesArray;
        })
    }

function Component1(){

var array2map = stepTwo();

console.log(array2map);
return(
    <div>
    {array2map.map(item => <p>item.name</p>)}
        </div>
    )


}




const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Component1 />);
```

Why does array2map come back as undefined?  That's what it says in the console log and what it says in the error I get as the result of trying to map something undefined.  That's my question, I don't know how much more verbose about it I can be, but this site is forcing me to write more.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not returning anything from your stepTwo function.

Comment: So what does the return statement belong to?

Comment: @DennisM to the `then` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Two things should be noted here:

Firstly, `stepTwo` does not return anything, the `return` statement it contains is for the `then` callback. The callback is run **after** `stepTwo` returns `undefined`.

Secondly, anything in a function component's top-level, like the `var array2Map = stepTwo()` is run before the component is mounted. Whereas `fetch` calls like `axios` should be made after the component has mounted.

Here's a solution.

```
async function axiosTest() {
    var response = await axios.get(BASEURL);
    return response.data;
}

async function stepTwo() {
    let data = await axiosTest();
    return data;
}

class Component1 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {array2Map: []};
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({array2Map: stepTwo()});
    }
```

Important advice: naming is very important in programming. Give appropriate names to your variables, methods & components. `stepTwo` doesn't do anything, that `axiosTest` already does. The latter can be used directly. I guess your axios call, returns a list of names. In that case, you can use `names` instead of `array2Map`.